# Sublime Text Carrying The Code One Line Above

Tags: editing

My problem is a code editing problem in Sublime text. After I delete some line, I want to carry whole code below in that line to one line above. Right now I am doing this via deleting the line manually. Are there any shortcuts that I can do it easily?

What I want to remove:

[image: What I want to remove]

What I want to achieve via shortcuts:

[image: What I want to achieve via shortcuts]

Comment: Please don't post images of code in SO (read [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) if you wonder why). Also, your problem appear to be unclear to me

Comment: @LoïcG. thanks i am editing it